# Gebrochenrationale Funktion

Tags: german-to-english, mathematics

Ich habe die Übersetzung von

> gebrochenrationale Funktion

gesucht. Zwar finde ich auf diversen Seiten die Übersetzung

> broken-rational function

, bei einer Rückwärtssuche, also der Eingabe von *broken-rational function* findet man allerdings fast ausschließlich die deutsche Übersetzung.

Auch auf diversen englischen Matheseiten habe ich den Begriff nicht gefunden.

Meine resultierende Frage ist also:

Gibt es die Klassifizierung einer rationalen Funktion als *gebrochen* im Englischen überhaupt? Oder wird sie lediglich von Deutschen im Englischen so übernommen?

Comment: Wenn ich [deutsche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationale_Funktion) und [englische](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) Wikipedia vergleiche, scheint die "gebrochenrationale Funktion" der "rational fraction" zu entsprechen.

Comment: *Rational fraction* bedeutet lediglich *rationaler Bruch*. Also eben das, woraus jede rationale Funktion besteht, egal ob gebrochenrational oder nicht.

Comment: This questions is for [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If enough of the community agrees on this, I will move the question. Although I find that is an equally good fit here as it is in Math.SE.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass man Englisch können muss, um deine Frage zu beantworten? Wenn ja, bist du falsch hier. In diesem Forum geht es um Deutsch. Es geht hier weder um Englisch noch um Mathematik.

Comment: Naja anhand der vorhandenen Kategorien und den Beschreibungen im help center empfand ich das schon als passend hier. Aber gut, ich beuge mich den Votes und lösche den Post.

Comment: Ich kann ihn übrigens nicht löschen, das müsste wohl ein Moderator übernehmen.

Answer (score 2):

Der gesuchte Begriff ist *rational function*. See, for instance, the text in *[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rational_function)*, and innumerable other places. In the EoM text you can also find the term *fractional-rational function* so you could use this -- if you have to. It is redundant, though, and rarely used.

Comment: Äh, nein. Eine "rational function" entspricht der "rationalen Funktion". Der OP wollte aber die Entsprechung für die gebrochenrationale Funktion.

Comment: @IGV Have you read the definition in EoM?

Comment: Ja. Und mit der Definition zur rationalen Funktion in der deutschen Wikipedia verglichen.

Comment: @IGV Äquivalent, nicht wahr?

Comment: Du hast zwar nicht ganz Recht, dennoch hast du den entscheidenden Hinweis gegeben: *rational function* bedeutet *rationale Funktion*, *fractional-rational function* bedeutet *gebrochenrationale Funtion* (und ist somit nicht redundand). Ich gebe dir ein +1, füge die Korrekte Antwort aber lieber noch hinzu.

Comment: @RoyPJ Prima, wenn es geholfen hat. Was ich u. a. mit der Antwort andeuten wollte, war, daß kein professioneller Mathematiker _fractional-rational function benutzen würde, weil die Definition von _rational Function_ ja schon den Quotient beinhaltet. Aus diesem Grund konntest Du auch selbst nichts finden.

Comment: @MartinPeters Das stimmt wohl im Allgemeinen, auch im Deutschen ist es ja in der professionellen Mathematik kaum vertreten. Dennoch ist es nützlich, um diese beiden Arten rationaler Funktionen zu unterscheiden.

Answer (score 2):

Mithilfe der Antwort von Martin Peters konnte das Problem gelöst werden:

> rational function

bedeutet *rationale Funktion*,

> fractional-rational function

bedeutet *gebrochenrationale Funktion*.

Answer (score 1):

Deine Frage ist zwar Off-Topic, aber ich beantworte sie trotzdem:
Der weit verbreitete deutsche Name an sich ist das Problem.

Das Wort »rational« bedeutet genau »gebrochen«. (Rationale Zahlen sind Brüche, lateinisch *ratio* = Verhältnis, Bruch).

Eine *gebrochenrationale* Funktion ist also dasselbe wie eine *gebrochengebrochene* oder eine *rationalrationale* Funktion. Das alles ist Unsinn.

Die Funktionen, die manche gerne mit dem Adjektiv *gebrochenrational* bezeichnen, heißen in Wahrheit [rationale Funktionen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationale_Funktion). Natürlich gibt es auch [ganzrationale Funktionen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganzrationale_Funktion), aber wenn man zwei ganzrationale Funktionen durcheinander teilt, erhält man eben eine **rationale** Funktion.

Comment: Als Teilzeitstudent der Mathematik kann ich dem nur zustimmen.

Comment: Als ehemaliger Vollzeitstudent der Mathematik kann ich dem nicht zustimmen. Zum einen ist es unerheblich, ob der Begriff so wortherkunfsmäßig Sinn ergibt. Rationale Funktionen kann man in die Klassen ganzrational, d.h. Polynome, und gebrochenrationale Funktionen unterteilen. Zum anderen habe ich zur Wortherkunft von *rational* aus dem Lateinischen lediglich Dinge wie „zur Vernunft, zur Rechnung, Berechnung gehörig“ gefunden.